# Azure SQL password less authentication with multiple user role

Tags: java, azure-sql-database, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity

I'm working on implementing Azure passwordless authentication for my Java app, which is hosted on AKS, and I'm using Azure SQL Single Database. I was able to achieve this by following the steps outlined in this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-sql-db-who-am-i/azure-sql-db-passwordless-connections/

However, I've encountered an issue where I can't use multiple database accounts with different roles (such as reader role or admin role) for the same database using Managed Identity. I'm wondering if there are any possibilities to map multiple managed identities for different roles in passwordless authentication?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!"

Comment: So you d like to have a single managed identity with multiple sql role or multiple managed identity with a single sql role ?

Comment: Hi, Multiple or single mange’s identity with multiple roles(reader,Admin)would be helpful

Comment: ok so what did not work following the documentation ?

Comment: In Above doc they suggested to use any one role only for single managed identity, like it might be reader or writer or admin. Since we are not passing the username or user I’d we are not able choose the user role via application.

Comment: For example - we need to use same database with different roles via password  less authentication for different app which we hosted in AKS.  Currently it’s taking managed identity user, we could able to set db permissions but we couldn’t able use multiple user roles like I mentioned above

Comment: sorry i dont really understand you mean. do you have script to share to explain what is not working ?

Comment: Sorry for that, I will update the question with detail diagram shortly, mean time I will explain you, In above document link(question) they mentioned script for db user creation and permission, we need two separate users like below for same database

alter role db_datareader add member [<read-user>];
alter role db_datawriter add member [<write-user>];

but unfortunately we are not sure how to achieve that using aks managed identity

Comment: did you create the two sql users: `create user [<managed-identity-name1>] from external provider;` ?

Comment: Only one managed-idenity will be mapped to AKS cluster right ? So not sure how to create another managed identity and map it via app ?  Shall we create two managed identity for single cluster ? Any way to tell app like which user to choose explicitly ?

Comment: each pod/app can use it's own identity so it s not a problem.

Comment: See the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/workload-identity-overview?tabs=dotnet